# how to configure docker to be able to use private insecure docker-registry

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-registry

Im trying to use my private (secured with nginx basic) over HTTP

I can login with my credentials but when I trying to push image docker says:

```
HTTP code 401, Docker will not send auth headers over HTTP.
```

So, set up ssl for me is not an option, I've read here about https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#insecure-registries but it does not work for my docker 1.3.2.

Can some one explain how to configure that to be able to work over HTTP.

Comment: You can follow an great tutorial here, just skip the SSL part, you should be able to have it working with login and without SSL:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04